# How to fix app engine server error when sending mail

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, smtp

I import mail with

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
```

and send mail with

```
sender = "bot@myapp.appspotmail.com"
receiver = "email@example.com"
subject = "hi"
body =  "Hi"

mail.send_mail(sender, receiver, subject, body)
```

When I run the app on localhost, sending mail works fine. But when I try to send mail on the deployed app, I get

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

What's wrong??

Comment: make explicit the parameters: `sender=senser..`

Comment: @presveva i tried that, didn't work. what's strange is that my other apps on app engine send mail just fine. could it be just a temporary server overload on google's side?

Comment: Apparently not [status](https://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/mail/2014/02/25)